# Does the fraction in the bottom right of the character card serve any purpose in Rogue Legacy?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Does the fraction stat in the bottom right of the character card in Rogue Legacy have any meaning, or is it just there for cosmetic purposes to make it look like a real deck-builder card?

[image: example of character card]

Comment: [Different template on their physical CCG](https://www.reddit.com/r/RogueLegacy/comments/2yge2y/rogue_legacy_the_card_game_from_pax_east_2015/). [Comment saying it's a throwback to MtG](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/711433-rogue-legacy/66836744), which it looks like a *very close* ripoff of.